# Parsing a response from JSON , ios?

Tags: ios, json

I have the below parameter in my json.

```
    {
"msg": "success",
"data": [
    {
        "FNAME": "test",
        "LNAME": null,
        "STATUS": null,
        "MOBILE1": "1234567890",
        "show_email": "1",
        "Info": [
            {
                "id": "73307",
                "NAME": "demo",
                "CONTACT": "",
                "WORKING_HOUR1": "[\"09:00 AM\",\"09:15 AM\",\"09:30 AM\",\"09:45 AM\",\"10:00 AM\"]",
                "WORKING_HOUR7": "",
                "DAY": "[\"Monday\",\"Wednesday\"]"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I am not able to understand how do I get values from it.

If I parse this I get the error

```
      NSError *myError = nil;
    NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];
      NSArray *results = [res objectForKey:@"data"];
       NSArray *Info=[results[0] objectForKey:@"Info"];
        NSArray *day=clinicInfo[1][@"DAY"];



         NSLog(@"%@", day[0]);
```

Error:

```
     'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectAtIndexedSubscript:
```

Comment: That isn't valid JSON

Comment: There is no variable called "clinicDay[0]" in your code. Did you mean Day[0]?

Comment: Yes Day[0] only sorry

Comment: nslog your dictionary res. I believe there is more to your json than what you have posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

From your JSON you want:

```
NSArray *days = json[@"data"][0][@"Info"][0][@"DAY"]
```

Also while your JSON is valid, the days and working hours are not in an array - they are a string.

You need something like this.

```
{
    "msg": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "FNAME": "test",
            "LNAME": null,
            "STATUS": null,
            "MOBILE1": "1234567890",
            "show_email": "1",
            "Info": [
                {
                    "id": "73307",
                    "NAME": "demo",
                    "CONTACT": "",
                    "WORKING_HOUR1": [
                        "09:00 AM",
                        "09:15 AM",
                        "09:30 AM",
                        "09:45 AM",
                        "10:00 AM"
                    ],
                    "WORKING_HOUR7": "",
                    "DAY": [
                        "Monday",
                        "Wednesday"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Firstly you are not using valid JSON.

```
{
    "DAY": [
        "Monday",
        "Wednesday"
    ]
}
```

You can use `NSJSONSerialization` to parse the JSON file, from which you should get a `NSDictionary`.

In that dictionary there should be a `NSArray` for the key "DAY", which contains 2 objects both strings, "Tuesday" and "Thursday".

eg. Where data is your JSON file

```
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];
if(!jsonError) NSArray *days = json[@"DAY"];
else NSLog(@"Error serialising JSON");
```

Comment: Yes there was some mistakes. Then what next. I have the json. The method I am trying is not right?

Comment: Try running this and see if the error comes up. Could you post the whole of the JSON file - if this is nested inside something else then of course it wont work!

Comment: Yes it is nested actually

Comment: So you need to adjust you code - as you haven't posted the whole JSON file, we have no way of knowing!

Comment: I have posted the whole json and also code I am doing. PLease have a look at it.

Comment: Here's a great tutorial that will walk you through everything you need: http://www.appcoda.com/fetch-parse-json-ios-programming-tutorial/

Comment: Well Day is in the form of string so I had to split the string and get the desired data.